# If string doesn't contain, then x, else y

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I have this code, which checks if the string contains certain words, then return blank message:

```
if(containsWords(['http', 'https'], message)) message = '';
```

Basically I'm looking for a similar line of code, except I want to filter out messages if they DOESN'T contain certain words.

So basically, if the string doesn't contain a word 'sony' for example, then it would return a blank message.

If it does, then all the messages with a word 'sony' will go through.

Comment: This is just plain JS so the [tag:puppeteer] seems irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need is to negate your function, to do this, simply add `!` before the function.

**Example**

```
if (!containsWords(['http', 'https'], message)) message = '';
```